# Django facebook integration error

Tags: python, django, facebook

I'm trying to integrate facebook into my application so that users can use their FB login to login to my site. I've got everything up and running and there are no issues when I run my site using the command line

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But this same code refuses to run when I try and run it through Apache.

I get the following error:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://helvetica/foodfolio/login
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'foodfolio.app',
 'foodfolio.facebookconnect']
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'facebook.djangofb.FacebookMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'facebookconnect.middleware.FacebookConnectMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/swat/website-apps/foodfolio/facebookconnect/templates/facebook/js.html, error at line 2
   Caught an exception while rendering: No module named app.models
   1 : <script type="text/javascript">
   2 :     FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function() {FB.Facebook.init("{{ facebook_api_key }}", " {% url facebook_xd_receiver %} ")});
   3 : 
   4 :     function facebookConnect(loginForm) {
   5 :         FB.Connect.requireSession();
   6 :         FB.Facebook.get_sessionState().waitUntilReady(function(){loginForm.submit();});
   7 :     }
   8 :     function pushToFacebookFeed(data){
   9 :         if(data['success']){
   10 :             var template_data = data['template_data'];
   11 :             var template_bundle_id = data['template_bundle_id'];
   12 :             feedTheFacebook(template_data,template_bundle_id,function(){});

Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/swat/website-apps/foodfolio/app/controller.py" in __showLogin__
  238.             context_instance = RequestContext(request))
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  108.     return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  178.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  779.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  71.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  946.                             autoescape=context.autoescape))
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/__init__.py" in render
  779.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  81.             raise wrapped

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /foodfolio/login
Exception Value: Caught an exception while rendering: No module named app.models
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are referencing `app.models`, which tends to work fine in development but fails in production.  Change it to `foodfolio.app.models`, and it should be fine.  This seems to be somewhere in your custom template tags.